# Windows Server 2008 remote printer

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to print in local computer(client) through remote desktop.

Server: Windows Server 2008 
Client: Windows 7 
In server and client I installed pdfPrinter.

I normal connected to the server through remote desktop, and pressed the print button in the application of the need to print, but in the dialog box to select the printer is only a server printers.

I need choose pdfPrinter installed **in client computer**.

Thanks for help.
Tom

(I did not forget to check printers in Local Resource tab.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you want to print to your local printer from a terminal server connection/RDP session.  If this is the case you will need to add the networked printer to the terminal server.  Once the printer driver has been added to the terminal server you can then select that to print to in your application.  You may also want to read [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753853%28WS.10%29.aspx) on Terminal Services Printing.